# Parametrized custom scripted similarity in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to calculate the similarity between two documents containing some **dense vectors** using a similarity score based on the L2 norm of these two vectors (their Euclidean distance). What I currently do is create my index with the following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "@id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "embedding": {
                "dims": <MY_DIM>,
                "type": "dense_vector"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then execute the following query (to get, for example, 5 closest documents):

```
{
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script": {
                "source": "1 / (1 + l2norm(params.query_vector, doc['embedding']))", 
                "params": {"query_vector": <MY_VECTOR>}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `script_score` in my ElasticSearch queries, I would like to encode my scripted score (in my case a similarity score based on the Euclidean distance) into `settings` (similar to what is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity)). I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "similarity": {
            "euclidean_similarity": {
                "type": "scripted",
                "script": {
                    "source": "1 / (1 + l2norm(params.query_vector, doc['embedding']))"
                }
            }
        }
    },
   "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "@id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "embedding": {
                "dims": 128,
                "type": "dense_vector",
                "similarity": "euclidean_similarity"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then have some 'simple' query that does not need to specify the formula, but uses this custom `euclidean_similarity` provided some `params`.

Is there any way to do something like this in Elasticsearch without defining custom plugins? And in general, is it possible to parameterize custom scripted similarities, and if yes, how do we pass the required parameters during the query time?

Comment: Wow, such an interesting and insightful question!